# Gettting Error 500 when trying Get from website using lwp::useragent

Tags: perl, mechanize, libwww-perl

Someone help me with this using lwp::Useragent please

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 0);
$mech->get($url);
my $content=$mech->content;
```

but getting **Error 500** when trying to get `https://camelcamelcamel.com/`

Comment: where is the rest of the code? where are you setting $url?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the site blocks requests from "bad" (undesired) user agents.  You may make `WWW::Mechanize` (`LWP::UserAgent`) present itself as another user agent using `agent` parameter for `new` or by calling `agent` method.  Full IE8 identification string fixed the problem.

I have tested it using `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1`.
[As listed by "[User Agent Switcher" plugin](http://chrispederick.com/work/user-agent-switcher/help/#user-agents) for Firefox]

[Short list of user agents (xml file)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrispederick/user-agent-switcher/master/development/source/content_common/useragentswitcher/xml/useragents.xml)
[Long list of user agents](http://techpatterns.com/forums/about304.html)

**WARNING**
The site(s) may use or choose to use other means to block unwanted requests.

Comment: i tried different IE8 string but nothing works can u give me the exact string @andrzej

Comment: I have added to the reply exact agent string used for test.